# Yii dependency injection basic

Tags: yii, dependency-injection, dependencies

Can anyone explain me DI basics please? I understand what it is, but I don't really know now, how to use DI container in practice. For example, I have 2 functions in the same controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $productsModel = new Products();
    $productsFormModel = new ProductsForm();
    $informationFormModel = new InformationForm();

    ....
}

public function actionInformation()
{
    $productsModel = new Products();
    $productsFormModel = new ProductsForm();
    $informationFormModel = new InformationForm();

    ....
}
```

So my two questions is:

1. As you see above, I use same models in these functions. It is good idea to initialized them into "public function init() {}" and then use them in all class globally or this is bad idea?
2. I think it should be better if these models would be injected into this controller, right? How to do it correctly?

I was created file DI.php, which I included into entry script. File content was:

```
<?php

\Yii::$container->set('products_model', 'app\models\Products');
\Yii::$container->set('products_form', 'app\models\ProductsForm');
\Yii::$container->set('information_form', 'app\models\InformationForm');

?>
```

So then I was able to get class app\models\Products instance globally (in every controller, view or model):

```
$instance_products = \Yii::$container->get('products_model');
$instance_products_form = \Yii::$container->get('products_form');
$instance_information_form = \Yii::$container->get('information_form');
```

But this is bad idea, right?

Please, answer someone my two questions. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Keeping things [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) is always a good idea.  The classes seem very related, so I suggest making this relationship explicit by creating a new model (e.g. `ProductsInfo`).  One could name the controller accordingly (`ProductsInfoController`), thereby clarifying the application structure.
2. Use dependency injection sparingly.  If there is a different way way, use that instead.  DI isn't a good fit for the described use-case.